# Intellij IDEA 14.1: Play Framework 2.3.8 Scala project import issue

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, intellij-14

I have created a Play framework 2.3.8 (Scala) project successfully, and ran it successfully as well. I just installed Intellij IDEA 14.1 and installed the Scala plugin during installation too. I am now trying to import the created project into the IDE; but I just can't find any guides to get me through it. I am stuck [here](http://www.mirkalami.com), as the images there show you. Any comprehensive help would be very much appreciated. Should I download anything further than what the default procedure does during the project creation with the Play Framework? If not, how do I set up the settings on the screen shown in the images on the page at the link provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "\bin\bin" in the error message?  It looks like you should remove the \bin from the path to the JVM - it should be just `c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_40`.

Comment: But \bin is where the JDK is installed. I can see it there.

Comment: Try changing it.  If it works, be happy; if not, let us know.

Comment: I tried it, and you were right. It worked. Thank you so much.